# New Relic app name in BlueMix

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, newrelic, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I've currently got a New Relic service bound to a Java app running under Liberty in Bluemix.

We are using a blue green deployment method to minimize down time when pushing a new version and as a consequence of this, the app name has a version suffix.

The app with version is being reported in New Relic.  When we push a new version, New Relic picks this up as a different instance ie:

- App v1
- App v2
- App v3

This breaks up the reporting timeline. If something is deployed in the morning, I cannot compare the data from the day before with today's set.

What I would like to do is override the app name in New Relic so that it just reports "App" with no version number. This should give me a continuous timeline for the app to view.  (Ideally, then I would have a script issue a deployment notice to New Relic so that it can indicate this with a label.)

New relic is added and bound using CF like so:

cf cups newrelic -p '{"licenseKey":"xxxxx"}'

There does not seem to be a way to set any other parameter besides the license key.

Answer (score 3):

Looking the the Liberty buildpack source, I see the application name gets appended to the server startup arguments as system properties.

```
  @java_opts << "-Dnewrelic.config.app_name=#{vcap_app_name}"
```

One thing you could possibly try is pushing a liberty server with the same system property and see if yours would take precedence [I don't know of any way for you to insure yours would have that precedence].   From my review of the source, it does not appear there is any built-in buildpack mechanism to override the application name passed to the new relic agent.  This seems like a good enhancement to add to the build pack.

Another possibility to consider.   As part of the blue/green deploy, why not always deploy to the same app name (e.g. myapp) and then do an app rename at blue/green deploy time.  For example:

```
cf rename myApp myApp_old_v2
cf push myApp ...     //pushing v3
```

In that type of scheme, the application would always report to new relic as myApp

Comment: You don't have to push a server package in order to set a Java option. You can set the user environment variable JAVA_OPTS and do a restage to apply it, or set JVM_ARGS and just do a RESTART to apply it. See https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/12/12/custom-configurations-java-jvm-liberty-runtime/ for more details.

Comment: I went with deploying the server directory with the JVM configuration file **jvm.options** containing `-Dnewrelic.config.app_name=myApp`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME environment variable.  You can do this on the command line using cf set-env APP_NAME ENV_VAR_NAME ENV_VAR_VALUE where ENV_VAR_NAME is NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME. This environment variable has the highest precedence which overrides the default New Relic app_name.

Comment: I use this approach. With a Blue/Green deployment situation I set the env var to both instances. It works like a charm. I however set two. `NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME ` and `NEW_RELIC_HOST_DISPLAY_NAME ` with the same values for both. I think you might need to set the host also to ensure that matches.